# Regex Match In Multiple Of n

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a string that starts with at least 4 spaces and in multiples of 4. So 4, 8, 12.

What i've got so far only matches at least 4 spaces.So it accepts 4, 5, 6...

```
/^[\s]{4,}\+/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the pattern which matches exactly four spaces inside a group and then make that group to repeat one or more times. And also you need to add a negative lookahead at the end, so that it won't match the string which has four spaces at the start followed  by another space.

```
/^(?:\s{4})+(?! )/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/2)

```js
var s = "    I have four spaces"
var s1 = "     I have five spaces"
alert(/^(?:\s{4})+(?! )/.test(s))
alert(/^(?:\s{4})+(?! )/.test(s1))
```

Comment: or `^(?:\s{4})+(?!\s)` or `^(?:\s{4})+\b`

Comment: Note that `\s` matches new line, so a series of 4 new lines (or a mix of new lines with space) matches the regex above. It's best to write `(?: {4})+(?! )` just to deal with just spaces (U+0020).